# How to align elements to vertical line

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I'm trying to make a website but ran into a problem. I need to align elements from div boxes to a vertical line. Something like in the picture (don't question my paint skills)

[image: example]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="sub-block">
        <a class="part1">(light gray block)</a>
        <a class="part2">(dark gray block)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to keep the `.part1` and `.part2` in `.sub-block` div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table layout can do this:

```css
.main-block {
  display:table;
}
.sub-block {
  display:table-row;
}

.sub-block > * {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:10px;
}
.part1 {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="sub-block">
        <a class="part1">aaa</a>
        <a class="part2">bb</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-block">
        <a class="part1">a a aaaaa</a>
        <a class="part2">b</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-block">
        <a class="part1">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
        <a class="part2">(dark gray block)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-block">
        <a class="part1">a</a>
        <a class="part2">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
    </div>
</div>
```